# How to create a new column that takes its values(as rows) from another two columns(names)?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset that has ID number, primary info, secondary info in R language using loops only. I need to create two new columns that takes values from primary info and secondary info. For example from this table(data) I have to get the second one:

- Initial data:

[image]

- What I need:

[image]

Comment: Hi there! If I understand your problem correctly, you want to transform a data frame from wide into long format. There are many questions on that on stackoverflow already, here a [link to some good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format).

Comment: Hi user18296782, Welcome to SO! First, please avoid screenshots. To increase your chances of being helped, please provide your data by copy-pasting the result of `dput(my_dataframe)` into your post. That said, here is a possible solution to get what you are looking for. If your `dataframe` is called `df` you could do: `df <- cbind(df[1], stack(df[-1])); df <- df[order(df$ID),]`. Cheers

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.